# How to use if else in Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I am learning Shell Scripting and i got stuck that in most languages like C,C++, 0 means false and 1 means true, but in below shell script I am not able to understand, how the output is generated

```
if [ 0 ]
then
    echo "if"
else
    echo "else"
fi
```

No matter what i write inside if block like instead of 0, I tried 1,2,true,false it is always running if condition. How this works in shell scripting.
And what shell script returns when the expression inside if statement is false.

Comment: You may find [Shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) useful. It automatically points out [this issue](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2159).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always executing `if` part because this condition:

```
[ 0 ]
```

will always be true as it checks if the string between `[` and `]` is not null/empty.

To correctly evaluate true/false use:

```
if true; then
   echo "if"
else
   echo "else"
fi
```

Comment: what will this expression return [ 10 -gt 100 ] because the string is not empty.

Comment: `10 -gt 100` is a valid shell test condition and it will evaluate to false

Answer (score 2):

There are no booleans in Bash.
But here are some examples that are interpreted *falsy*:

- Empty value: ""
- Program exiting with non-zero code

A `0` as in your example is not *falsy*, because it's a non-empty value.

An example with empty value:

```
if [ "" ]
then
    echo "if"
else
    echo "else"
fi
```

An example with non-zero exit code (assuming there's no file named "nonexistent"):

```
if ls nonexistent &> /dev/null
then
    echo "if"
else
    echo "else"
fi
```

Or:

```
if /usr/bin/false
then
    echo "if"
else
    echo "else"
fi
```

Or:

```
if grep -q whatever nonexistent
then
    echo "if"
else
    echo "else"
fi
```